# "unless he is invited" vs. "if he is not invited"

Tags: conditionals

[image: snippet of test question which is reproduced below]

- Mr. Dev will not go to the wedding reception "without being called."

  1. if he is not invited.
  2. till he is invited.
  3. unless he is invited.
  4. no improvement

I am confused why the answer is only #3 , I feel #1 to be correct as well.

Please help me understand why #3 is the correct answer but not #1.

Comment: I agree that the first answer works about as well as the third. It's also not bad as is (no improvement).

Comment: The two nots in the sentence make #1 confusing, #3 is precise.

Comment: Hello sagar, would you mind rotating your picture so that its content conforms to the usual orientation for English text?

Comment: The sense of #3 is closer to the original - that is, there is a slight implication (not strong enough to be an obligation on Mr Dev's part) that if he *is* invited, he might attend. #1 focuses only on the non-attendance, while #2 overstates the 'he might attend' implication.

Comment: Pretend the original phrase used: *without a positive*

Other analyses are possible and please consider:
1.  if he is not invited = with a negative  (if he; with) + (not invited; negative)
2. till he is invited    = with a positive (till he; with) + (invited; positive)
3.  unless he is invited  = without a positive  (unless he; without) + (invited; positive)
4.  no improvement  = neutral